# Error "a name is not defined" when using a variable in expression

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to test against multiple environments with a single test case using the passing in of a variable from the command line. Using the following command line:

```
robot --variable TESTENV:prod advertisingdisclosure_Page.robot
```

I need to test the value of TESTENV and depending on the value passed in set a different variable, specifically a URL, to the appropriate value. With the following code in the first keyword section of the test case I get an error:

```
IF   ${TESTENV}  ==  "uat"
    $(MAIN_URL)=    Set Variable    ${env_data['uat_url']}
ELSE IF    ${TESTENV}  ==  "dev"
    ${MAIN_URL}=   Set Variable   ${env_data['dev_url']}
ELSE IF    ${TESTENV} == "prod"
    ${MAIN_URL}=   Set Variable   ${env_data["prod_url"]}
ELSE
    Fail    "No URL specified"
END
```

I get the following error:

```
Evaluating expression 'prod' failed: NameError: name 'prod' is not defined nor importable as module
```

The examples I have found show how to use the Global Variable directly, but not how to evaluate it for a specific value.

Help.

Jeff

Comment: Maybe double quotes for all operands when comparing strings?

Answer (score 6):

You need to put quotes around the variable name - otherwise the framework just puts its value in, and passes that expression to python.
Thus it becomes `prod == '"uat"`, and py rightfully complains there is no defined variable `prod`.

The fix is simple - just surround the usage in quotes, and after substitution this will become a string comparison:

```
"${TESTENV}" == "uat"
```

Alternatively you can use another syntax - no curly brackets, which tells RF to use/pass the variable itself, not its value, and then it will be a defined one for python:

```
$TESTENV == "uat"
```